# How can I scan through a raw text file?

Tags: android, android-listview, java.util.scanner, android-file

I have text files in the raw folder that I would like to use in my app. I am using ListFragments and depending on what item is selected I want to load that files text in a new layout.

I can properly load the text fine but I would like to be able to scan the file previously so that I can have the first line of the file be the title that is displayed in the ListView. I have a method that determines the number of files in the raw folder and adds the names to the ArrayList.

Here is my method:

```
    private void listRaw() {
    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();

    for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++) {

            myArrayList.add(fields[count].getName());
    }
}
```

The problem i am having is setting up a scanner. I do not know how to tell the scanner to scan this specific file. I tried making a new File object and used the Scanner(File) but I do not think I am declaring the file name properly nor if this is even the best way to get this done. Normally if you know the file name you can just simply do:

Scanner fileReader = new Scanner("filename");

but in this loop I never actually have the file name set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have text files in the raw folder that I would like to use in my app

I am assuming that "the raw folder" means the `res/raw/` resource directory in your project.

> I do not know how to tell the scanner to scan this specific file

That is because there is no file. The file exists on your development machine. The representation of the raw resource at *runtime* is just that: a raw resource. Under the covers, it's effectively an entry in a ZIP file.

You need to get the `R.raw` value for a raw resource, then use `getResources().openRawResource()` to get an `InputStream` that you can pass to a `Scanner`.

Unless you have different editions of these raw resources for different configurations (e.g., language), you might find it easier to work with the `assets/` directory and `AssetManager` for packaging text files with your app.